# What's the best way to sort a list while also keeping its original index?

Tags: python

```
l = ['0.40165794', '0.43157488', '0.65739065', '0.5142521']
```

I want to transform the list into the following form:

```
 l = [('0.65739065', 2), ('0.5142521', 3), ('0.43157488', 1), ('0.40165794', 0)]
```

I can first create a dict to store the value-index pair, then sort l in descending order, then for each sorted element, look up the dict to the the index, then compose the list of tuples.

This seems quite complicated. Is there a better way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is with `enumerate()` to generate the indexes and then use `key` to specify how to sort:

```
s = sorted(enumerate(l), key=lambda x: x[1])
print(s)
```

This will sort in ascending order. Descending order is left as an exercise for the reader. As is reversing the order of the `(index, value)` pairs if desired.

Comment: I guess the OP wants the index to be the second index in elements like `(value, index)` not `(index, value)`

Comment: @aminrd That's a good point. My solution gives a list of `(index, value)` pairs. IDK if the order is important to the OP or not.

Comment: Well, the OP can just remap the tuple to reverse the the order if need be: `s = [(e, i) for (i, e) in s]`